# How to import always used services into one service and use it in components?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular project, there exists 4 services which is used by most of the components. What I'm attempting to achieve is instead of importing each one of them individually in the components, import those 4 services into 1 and use that one service in the components.

What I have is the following **but** I'm looking for a better approach.

```
// bundled.service.ts


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// The following are the services used all over the project

import { ConfirmService } from '../utility/confirm.service';
import { LoadingService } from '../utility/loading.service';
import { SnackbarService } from '../utility/snackbar.service';
import { ErrorHandlingService } from '../error/error-handling.service';

@Injectable()
export class BundledService {

    constructor(
        private confirmSer: ConfirmService,
        private loadingSer: LoadingService,
    ) {
    }

    openDialog(warningText: string) {
        this.confirmSer.openDialog(warningText);
    }

    toogleLoading(loading: boolean) {
        this.loadingSer.toogleLoading(loading);
    }

// ...and so on for the other two
}
```

Comment: I'd probably implement the way you did.

Comment: In the Angular documentation, they define a `CoreModule` to combine a set of services. There are details on how to build one: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Answer (score 0):

One option you might consider is using a **mixin**.  This pattern allows you to build up a class from simpler partial classes.  The TypeScript documentation includes a very thorough write up of how to use this pattern:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

Here's a simplified code example from the link above:

```
class MyService1 {
    public openDialog() {

    }
}

class MyService2 {
    public toggleLoading() {

    }
}

class MySuperService implements MyService1, MyService2 {
    openDialog: () => void;
    toggleLoading: () => void;
}

applyMixins(MySuperService, [MyService1, MyService2]);

////////////////////////////////////////
// In your runtime library somewhere
////////////////////////////////////////

function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
    baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
            derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
        });
    });
}
```